# After shutting down computer how to reactivate a django server

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

'm very new to django web development in python and I'm currently following a course on building a simple django website.

The problem is, I went to sleep and decided to shut down my computer. After sometime I need to reactivate the website or something because the website just says 'This site can't be reached'.

I opened up the code and I'm not sure if I'm suppose to write a certain command in the terminal or something. The terminal is empty when before it was running the website and had stuff there.

I do understand that it is going to stop running the website when I shut down my computer because it's my computer hosting it, but I just need to know how to start running it again.

So how do I 're-activate' a django website?

Comment: you can start by reading the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/

Comment: You need to run the Python script on system startup. If on windows, you can use the following method: [Run a script on start up on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/954950/run-a-script-on-start-up-on-windows-10) with a .bat file starting the Python script.

Comment: If its development you just need to run in terminal in django project folder: `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: It quite depends on what operating system do you use - if it's Windows, I highly recommend configuring service for that. Otherwise just put it into Apache using Django deployment guideline.